# Mapbox map not correctly displaying javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, mapbox-gl-js

I have added map to my site and everything works fine
when the map is placed in a parents div with display:flex.

But I have a requirement to display my map after the user clicks on a button
so the parent div in which map is placed at the loading of page has display:none
and then when clicking on button it becomes flex.

But when clickng on button something strange happens to map
[map not shown correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABhgf.png)

I found out that when resizing it becomes normal [map shown correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDAFr.png)

here is the map css:

```
#add_adv_map {
    width: 90%;
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

and html

```
<div class="add-adv__info__item add-adv__info__item--block add-info-address">
     <div class="add-adv__form__title">adress</div>
     <input type="text" name="flat_location" class="object_parameter_input object_parameter_input--large"
                 id="add_adv_address"
      <div id='add_adv_map'></div>  required> <!--map container-->
</div>
```

havent found any questions on this topic
and any answers either

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue
I simply resized window by some value and then returned size back
Haven't found any better solution

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).